# Multilingual wordpress site with own domains for every language

Tags: dns, wordpress, multilingual

The goal is to have one wordpress instalation with varius language versions which share media library (images...), user accounts etc. but also work on their own second level domains so I have website.com and website.cc and website.de and similar but I dont need to manage three different wordpresses.

I guess that should be possible to do using some DNS magic but I havent been able to google any how-to to achieve that. Can someone help please?

Comment: Did you came up with a good solution yet? I'm looking for the same thing..

Answer (score 0):

I have done this recently with a site. All of the domains required were pointed to the same place by using Domain Aliases in Plesk.

In the wp-config.php I checked to see which domain the page was being requested from by using the following a switch statement.

```
$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]
```

I then set things like WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME as well as defining a LANGUAGE which could be used within the theme within the switch statement.

We used custom fields to allow admins to enter different languages and then added a content filter into functions.php to switch these on the frontend based on the language defined in the wp-config.php.

```
function content_translation($content) {
     $lang = SITE_LANG;

     if($lang == 'de'){
         $content = get_meta('de_content');
     } else {
         return $content;
     }
     return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'content_translation');
```

There may be better ways to do this but this is what I came up with a few versions of WordPress back.